# Use HttpGet request with model as parameter with RestSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, request, restsharp

I'm currently using [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) to do request to an ASP.NET CORE API so I create an extension method in my windows forms solution like:

```
 public static (string response, string content) Request(string route, Method method, string model, string clientAPI, string token = null, string methodName = null, string paramName = null, bool isGetWithModel = false)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(clientAPI);
            var request = new RestRequest(route, method);

            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            if (token != null)
            {
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + token);
            }
            if (model != null && method == Method.POST)
            {
                request.AddJsonBody(model);
                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            }
            else if(method == Method.GET)
            {

                if (model != null && !isGetWithModel) request.AddParameter(paramName, model);

                if (isGetWithModel)
                {
                    request.AddJsonBody(model);
                }

                request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            }
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

            var content = response.Content;

            return (response: response.StatusCode.ToString(), content: content);
        }
```

And I call it as:

```
 var (response, content) = Helpers.Request(GetCustomerContactRoute, Method.GET, customerSelectJsonModel, Settings["ClientApi"], this.Token, isGetWithModel: true);
```

My API method looks like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromQuery] CustomerSelectModel model)
    {
    //....Code Here
    }
```

As you can see API method and request from RestSharp is an `HttpGet`

The problem is when request is HttpGet and it have a model in API, I send model with restsharp as:

```
 if (isGetWithModel)
            {
                request.AddJsonBody(model);
            }
```

But when API receive it, it just have all values null. The weird thing is if I change that method in API as `[HttpPost]` remove [FromQuery] int o API method and then do the request as `Method.HttpPost` it works correctly, it receive model correctly.

Working method with HttpPost

```
//Call
var (response, content) = Helpers.Request(GetCustomerContactRoute, Method.POST, customerSelectJsonModel, Settings["ClientApi"], this.Token);

//API method


        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(CustomerSelectModel model)
        {
            //...code here
        }
```

I don't have an idea whit this occurs, help is very appreciated. Regards

Comment: You should really not use `RestSharp` in an ASP.NET Core project. You should be using `IHttpClientFactory` and `HttpClient` to do REST calls. There is tons of information online to back this up.

Comment: The problem is I do the request from really old windows forms app, so I can not use `ClientFactory` there @Andy

Comment: Sorry, i saw the ASP.NET Core code and thought you were doing it in your WebAPI.

Comment: Try changing `public async Task<IActionResult> Get(CustomerSelectModel model)` to `public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] CustomerSelectModel model)`

Comment: API is ASP.NET Core but request come from winform app @Andy

Comment: But thats only the name of method I thiink that does not matter, I can use GetCustomers and it should works  @Andy